# Mirror that flips polarisation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, polarization

Is it possible to build a mirror which not just reflects a photon but also flips its polarisation from horizontal tho vertical (or vice versa)?

The reason why I ask is the following: If I put an optical device in front of the mirror which flips the polarisation, this device will act twice on the photon (once on the way there and once on the way back). Thus the photon ends up with the same polarisation.

Is there a common solution to this problem?

Note that in my case the photon must take the same way back. So tilting the mirror is no solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the device is called a *Faraday mirror* and it consists of a normal mirror following a [Faraday rotator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_rotator). The latter is a magneto-optical device that rotates the state of polarization of light passing through it in a non-reciprocal manner. The most well-known application of Faraday rotators is to provide [optical isolation](http://www.leysop.com/faraday.htm).

The Faraday effect is wavelength dependent so it may not work as per your expectations if you source is too broadband; commercially-available Faraday rotators have a bandwidth [in the $10-50\,$nm range](http://www.newport.com/Fiber-Optic-Faraday-Rotator-Mirrors/835750/1033/info.aspx#tab_Specifications). Some rotators may allow you the possibility of tuning the [central wavelength](http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2996) but I am not sure if it is easy to order just the free-space rotator element alone (most vendors seem to offer buying only the complete isolator assembly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reformulated my question here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141622/flip-of-polarisation-of-light but the answer here is good too (even if I expected something else).

Comment: [In this paper](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/apl/104/11/10.1063/1.4869127)(CNRS-Onera), they are able to get similar effects for wider bands (3.25-4.25µm in this case), using sub-wavelength structures.