# Flip of polarisation of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, polarization

Consider an optical experiment with photons or light pulses.

Is there an optical element that acts in the polarisation degree of freedom like the unitary
$$
U = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\quad \text ?
$$
I choosed the basis such that 
$$
|H\rangle =  
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\;,\quad
|V\rangle =  
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If yes, then a photon that passes this device twice would expirience a flip in the polarisation:
$$
U^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;,
$$
like $U|H\rangle = |V\rangle$ and $U|V\rangle = -|H\rangle$.

Does it exist?

Comment: The result of passing through this element twice would be to "flip the polarization" - or if you like, it would be a 180 degree phase shift. That would just be a $\lambda/2$ element. But something that does this "after you pass through twice" is more interesting.
What you are asking for is an element that rotates the polarization angle by 90 degrees. I have a hunch that you could achieve this with a birefringent element, but I'm not sure that can be done when you don't know the incident polarization angle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical matrix for an *optically active* element that rotates the light polarisation. A cuvette of water with sugar will do the job. Proportional to the sugar concentration, you can obtain arbitrary wave rotation.

Note that the U matrix has imaginary eigenvectors (1+i)/sqrt(2) and (1-i)/sqrt(2). Accordingly, unlike λ/4 plates, the eigenwaves of such a system are left- and right-circularly polarized.

Comment: Note also that optical activity is time reversible. A different result can be obtained by defining both off-diagonal elements of U as imaginary, in which case the forward and backward waves would be rotated in the same direction breaking the time-reversal symmetry. 

This effect occurs e.g. in statically magnetized bismuth-iron-grenade and is employed in optical insulators.